# R leaflet map, add button that expands on hover and shows some text

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

Expanding on an example from `addEasyButton` in RStudios **leaflet** package, I wonder if it is possible to create a button that automatically expands on hover to show some text?
Something like the code below, but not via alert on click but via expand on hover (behaving similar to the layer control button).

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addEasyButton(
    button = easyButton(
      icon = 'fa-info',
      onClick = JS('function(btn, map){ alert("sometext"); }')
    )
  )
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I use leaflet and would like to also know how to create this feature.